# sed repeat string on every line

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed, grep

I have a file `inventory.txt` that contains hundreds of lines.  It lists data relevant to Customer IDs/Names, Inventory IDs/Names, and Product IDs/Names.  The general setup of the file that on any given line a `customerId=123` may appear.  Following this line, an `inventoryId=abc` line will appear.  This file looks something like this:

```
<> START OF FILE
Customer ID=9000, Customer Name=Acme, Inc
Inventory ID=INV_ID1, Inventory Name=Acme_INV1
Product ID=100, Product Name=Banana
Product ID=200, Product Name=Apple
Inventory ID=INV_ID2, Inventory Name=Acme_INV2
Product ID=100, Product Name=Banana
Product ID=300, Product Name=Kiwi
Customer ID=7500, Customer Name=Anvil, Corp
Inventory ID=INV_ID3, Inventory Name=Anvil_INV1
Product ID=200, Product Name=Apple
<> END OF FILE
```

What I would like to do using SED, or any alternative that works well enough, is to create a CSV formatted file that has a single line of data for each customer/inventory combination that includes just the Customer ID/Name and Inventory ID/Name fields.  So the output would look something like:

```
"9000", "Acme, Inc.", "INV_ID1", "Acme_INV1"
"9000", "Acme, Inc.", "INV_ID2", "Acme_INV2"
"7500", "Anvil, Inc.", "INV_ID3", "Anvil_INV1"
```

I understand how to use SED to format that input data into a CSV file output with commas and quotations, but I am having trouble in figuring out how to force the `Customer ID` and `Customer Name` to repeat at the beginning of every `Inventory ID` and `Inventory Name` line.

Comment: This is tricky in sed, and perhaps impossible.  I've been trying to envision a way to use sed's "*hold space*" to keep a copy of your Customer ID and Name, then for each Inventory line, append the relevant data to the *hold space* and print, but it seems that any *use* of the hold space also modifies it, therefore invalidating it for the second (or more) Inventory line for a particular customer.  While it's interesting and educational to struggle with ways to do this in `sed`, if you just want to get the job done, steve's awk one-liner looks like it'll work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way using `awk`:

```
awk -F= '{ sub(/,.*/,"",$2) } /^Customer ID/ { r = $2 OFS $3 } /^Inventory ID/ { print "\"" r, $2, $3 "\"" }' OFS="\", \"" inventory.txt
```

Or a `sed` solution:

```
sed -n '/^Customer ID/ h; /^Inventory ID/ { G; s/.*=\([^,]*\).*=\([^\n]*\).*=\([^,]*\).*=\(.*\)/"\3", "\4", "\1", "\2"/; p }' inventory.txt
```

Results:

```
"9000", "Acme, Inc", "INV_ID1", "Acme_INV1"
"9000", "Acme, Inc", "INV_ID2", "Acme_INV2"
"7500", "Anvil, Corp", "INV_ID3", "Anvil_INV1"
```

---

`awk` explanation:

```
 OFS="\", \""          # set the output field separator to: ", "

-F=                    # split the line into three fields using the '=' character

{ sub(/,.*/,"",$2) }   # one each line of input, remove everything trailing a
                       # comma from field two.

/^Customer ID/ { ... } # if the line starts with 'Customer ID'; do

r = $2 OFS $3          # build a record using field two and three separated by 'OFS'

/^Inventory ID/ {...}  # if the line starts with 'Inventory ID'; do

print "\"" r, $2, $3 "\""   # print out a double-quote, the record, OFS, $2, OFS, 
                            # $3 and lastly a double quote
```

`sed` explanation:

> Disable default printing with the `-n` flag. When a line starts with "Customer ID", copy the line to hold space. When a line that starts with "Inventory ID" is found, append the hold space to the current line. Use some magical regex to re-arrange the different fields and fix the formatting.

Comment: you should consider that customer name has comma.

Comment: Darn, you beat me to it again.  **+1**.

Comment: Can you please comment on what your code is doing?  I'm relatively new to BASH scripting.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sure, I'll add an explanation regarding the `awk` solution in a minute. But as you can see, I've added a `sed` solution. I just want to see if I can first reduce the regex to make it more readable. I think it could be done.

Comment: Thanks guys. Reciprocated :-)

Comment: @TravisCrooks: I've added a bit of an explanation regarding the two commands. Please let me know if I haven't explained things clearly enough. HTH!

Comment: This is great!!  Thank you so much for providing the 2 solutions.  I'm in the midst of configuring the SED solution for my needs.  I greatly appreciate your assistance!! :)

Comment: @steve:  If one of the fields were to have a close bracket `]` in it, how would that be handled?  For example, if the customer name field was defined as `Customer Name=Acme, Inc.]`, how would the close bracket also be removed along with the `\n`?

Comment: I've defined a field as being between a `=` and, a `,` or end of line (i.e. an `\n` character). So the bracket would be included in the field. It would not be removed with the `\n`.

Answer (score 1):

Perl solution:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw(say);

my ($customer, $name);
while (<>) {
    if (/Customer ID=(.*), Customer Name=(.*)/) {
        ($customer, $name) = ($1, $2);
    } elsif (/Inventory ID=(.*), Inventory Name=(.*)/) {
        say join ', ' => map qq("$_"), $customer, $name, $1, $2;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

another awk one-liner without using FS

```
awk -vq="\"" '/^(Cus|Inv)/{f=$0~/^Cus/;gsub(/[^,]*=/,q);sub(/,/,q",");c=f?$0q:c;if(!f)print c","$0q}' file
```

test:

```
kent$  echo "Customer ID=9000, Customer Name=Acme, Inc
Inventory ID=INV_ID1, Inventory Name=Acme_INV1
Product ID=100, Product Name=Banana
Product ID=200, Product Name=Apple
Inventory ID=INV_ID2, Inventory Name=Acme_INV2
Product ID=100, Product Name=Banana
Product ID=300, Product Name=Kiwi
Customer ID=7500, Customer Name=Anvil, Corp
Inventory ID=INV_ID3, Inventory Name=Anvil_INV1
Product ID=200, Product Name=Apple"|awk -vq="\"" '/^(Cus|Inv)/{f=$0~/^Cus/;gsub(/[^,]*=/,q);sub(/,/,q",");c=f?$0q:c;if(!f)print c","$0q}'                                   
"9000","Acme, Inc","INV_ID1","Acme_INV1"
"9000","Acme, Inc","INV_ID2","Acme_INV2"
"7500","Anvil, Corp","INV_ID3","Anvil_INV1"
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r '/^Customer/{h;d};/^Inventory/!d;G;s/.*=([^,]*).*=([^\n]*).*=([^,]*).*=(.*)/"\3", "\4", "\1", "\2"/' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a gawk extension to the [`match()`](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html#index-g_t_0040code_007bmatch_0028_0029_007d-function-1373) function

```
gawk '
    match($0, /^Customer ID=([^,]+), Customer Name=(.*)/, cust) {
        c_id=cust[1]; c_name=cust[2]
        next
    }
    match($0, /^Inventory ID=([^,]+), Inventory Name=(.*)/, inv) {
        printf "\"%s\",\"%s\",\"%s\",\"%s\"\n", c_id, c_name, inv[1], inv[2]
    }
' filename
```

outputs

```
"9000","Acme, Inc","INV_ID1","Acme_INV1"
"9000","Acme, Inc","INV_ID2","Acme_INV2"
"7500","Anvil, Corp","INV_ID3","Anvil_INV1"
```